# traefik v2 redirect TCP requests

Tags: kerberos, traefik

we habe following situation.
We are using Kerberos on a tomcat running in a docker swarm as reverse proxy we use traefik also hosted in docker swarm.
Kerberos needs to passthrough the SSL request via TCP router. This works no problem. But now we want to redirect requests to port 80 also to tcp router port 443?

We tried a lot, but no success at all :-(

Here is the traefik configuration

```
labels:
    traefik.tcp.routers.example.entrypoints: https
    traefik.tcp.services.example.loadbalancer.server.port: '8443'
    traefik.tcp.routers.example.service: example
    traefik.tcp.routers.example.tls.passthrough: 'true'
    traefik.constraint-label: traefik-public
    traefik.tcp.routers.example.rule: HostSNI(`example.com`)
    traefik.docker.network: traefik-public
    traefik.enable: 'true'
    traefik.tcp.routers.example.tls: 'true'
```

regards
Meex